# What is the name of this extension of the maximum independent set problem?

Tags: np-complete, np-hard, approximation, weighted-graphs

Problem:  we have an undirected graph. Each vertex $v$ has a weight of $w_v$.  For each vertex $v$, a nonnegative number $a_v$ is given,  and for each edge $e$, a nonnegative number $b_e$ is given.  We call an edge "activated" if both of its endpoints are chosen. Now,  we want to choose a maximum weighted set of vertices,  such that for each vertex $v$,  the sum of $b_e$ for all activated edges $e$ adjacent to $v$ is not more than $a_v$.  If all $a_v=0$ and all $b_e>0$, it will be the maximum weighted independent set problem.

Do you know the name of this problem? Has anyone seen any papers about this problem?

Comment: Can $a_v$ and $b_v$ be real numbers as well or just integers?

Comment: They are real numbers